# Is it worth inlining a function containing one tight loop?

Tags: c, inline, compiler-optimization, ram

Suppose we have a function that contains only one tight loop, e.g.:

```
int Prime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Is it worth inlining this function: `inline int Prime(int n)`? Note, for the purpose of this question, assume code replacement **will** happen if we inline the function. So now the question is, whether that's a good thing to do in this case.

I would say no, because if the CPU executes a `call` instruction and starts executing this function with everything else being pushed into the stack, then the integers `i` and `n` might fit into the registers and the whole for loop would execute only on registers.

However, if we inline the function and the code gets inserted as a part of some bigger block, then `i` and `n` might end up on the stack and the for loop would be accessing RAM to continuously query their values.

Is this a reason to not use the keyword `inline` for such function?

Are there other reasons why we should not inline such function?

Comment: `inline` affects the one definition rule and is otherwise mostly just a hint to the compiler these days. With optimizations enabled, your compiler may or may not inline the function with or without the keyword, depending on how it feels.

Comment: Try it, and see if your performance improves.

Comment: `if we inline the function` `inline` does not mean the function will get inlined.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I know, but if it does end up being inlined, will that be a performance improvement or loss?

Comment: You can always write the code inline yourself - it's quite short - but the major execution time isn't taken by the function call but the poor algorithm. You can immediately halve the execution time by checking only odd divisors, after checking for `2` or being even.

Comment: If it ends up being inlined or not, nowadays the keyword `inline` has not really much to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, if we inline the function and the code gets inserted as a part of some bigger block, then i and n might end up on the stack and the for loop would be accessing RAM to continuously query their values.

Not really, no sane compiler when ran with proper optimization flags will put loop variables in RAM. At best, even if the arguments are passed through the stack, then you will see one or more moves into registers before the start of the loop (with appropriate push/pop instructions before and after the loop to preserve the original values of the registers).

For example:

```
push regA   ; save original regA
mov regA, 2 ; use regA as i
; ... loop ...
pop regA    ; restore regA
```

---

About the `inline` keyword: it's purely an hint. Modern compilers will not respect it. If you want to *force* inlining, then you can use compiler-specific flags, like for example for GCC or Clang:

```c
inline __attribute__((always_inline)) int Prime(int n) { ...
```

---

**Would it be worth to inline such function?** It's not possible to say beforehand. One can only guess, but even then, guessing would require seeing the code around the actual function call. In general you can only say if inlining is useful after testing and profiling the code with the inlined version VS the code with the non-inlined version.

> Are there other reasons why we should not inline such function?

As [@P__J__](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6110094/p-j) notices in the comments: inlining increases the memory footprint of the program if inlined function is called in many places. Because of that many compilers have a limit of the size of all and/or this particular inlined function. Usually inlining increases the size of the program code.

If your goal is to have a very small program, then inlining is not a good idea.

Comment: So would it be worth to force inlining such function, or is there another reason for not doing that?

Comment: @mercury0114 it's not possible to say beforehand if it would be worth to inline the function. One can only *guess*, but even then the code around the actual call would be needed to guess. In general you can only say if inlining is useful after testing and profiling the code with the inlined version VS the code with the non-inlined version.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli but inlining is not about preserving registers or keeping the variables there. It is about the function call itself and we inline functions if we want to avoid overhead related to the function call, function prologue and epilogue

Comment: @P__J__ op was worried inlining could cause too many ram accesses. I answered that no, with or without inlining that would not be the problem. Maybe I should remove the `call` to make that clearer.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli The problem is more complex. Inlining increases the memory footprint of the program if the inlined function is called in many places. Because of that many compilers have a limit of the size of all and/or this particular inlined function. Usually inlining increases the size of the program code.

Comment: That is the reason why if you compile with -Os there is no automatic inlining :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a reason to not use the keyword inline for such function?

Direct answer: no.
The compiler would notice that `i` and `n` are accessed very often, and allocate registers to them, at least temporarily for the duration of the loop. Even if the surrounding function uses all available registers.

Comment: but inlining is not about preserving registers or keeping the variables there. It is about the function call itself and we inline functions if we want to avoid overhead related to the function call, function prologue and epilogue

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "worth".

If you are going to call these functions very frequently and the function call overhead (preparing for the call, the call itself, function prologue and epilogue) matters then it is worth it. But `inline` keyword is rather a hint for the compiler than the order.

In many circumstances, the compiler will inline it even without the `inline` keyword.

https://godbolt.org/z/oKMeej

If you want to be sure that the function is always inlined then usually you need to use some compiler extension to force the inlining.

https://godbolt.org/z/jTaMc4

Or if you do not want to inline function (for example during the debugging)

https://godbolt.org/z/M4j5E7

Answer (score 1):

`inline` is a misnomer and it is basically a keyword to modify linkage. `inline` exists so that you can provide two functions that compiler may choose from:

```
// file.h
// a definition of the inline function
inline void function(void) {
    // some algorithm
}
// forward declaration of not inline function
void function(void);


// file.c
void function(void) {
   // the same algorithm
}

// main.h
#include "file.h"
int main() {
    function(); // will it call file.h:function? or file.c:function?
                // compiler may choose
}
```

`inline` is *not* inlining the call - it's merely a **hint** that compiler **may** consider the function for inlining, but... compiler may consider anything for inlinging - there's no point in hinting him. With todays compilers that optimize aggressively, can use link time optimization, can merge same function definition across multiple translation units - just forget about `inline` at all. Nowadays I see usage of `inline` *only* with `static` functions to disable unused function warnings. And `static inline` functions are the only portable between gnu89 and nowadays C.

> Is this a reason to not use the keyword inline for such function?

No.

> So would it be worth to force inlining such function, or is there another reason for not doing that?

Remember about the [rules of optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimizationClub). Do not optimize by guessing. Only inspecting the generated assembly or profiling of your code compiled under specific compiler, compiler version and compiler options will answer a question if such code such be force inlined or not.

Comment: If inline function is not static it will always be compiled as a "normal" function with external linkage and inlined when possible.

Comment: I always understood it that [here](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.4p7): `If all of the file scope declarations for a function in a translation unit include the inline function specifier without extern, then the definition in that translation unit is an inline definition.`. The `inline` has to be before anything else, corrected that, but the declaration is allowed after. (Or maybe should the `void function(void);` be also removed to make `inline void function(void) {}` an inline definition?... I never know)